# How to rotate SigningCredentials every 30 days?

Tags: c#, .net-core, identityserver4, x509certificate2

I have an implementation of ISigningCredentialStore which implements GetSigningCredentialsAsync() method. This method generates a new SigningCredentials by creating an X509Certificate2 and stores it into database. The certificate expires every 30 days.

I want to run a background process that checks everyday whether the certificate is expiring in 24 hours, and create a new certificate if it is.

Do we need to add AddSigningCredential() in startup if we implement ISigningCredentialStore. How to load new SigningCredentials in IdentityServer automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, you can create your own `ISigningCredentialStore` and `IValidationKeysStore` implementations and you can encapsulate any logic you like within that custom implementation, including key-rollover without an app restart.

Note that you should ensure that your clients don't cache discovery data for more than the rollover overlap period.